# Is there a place to find the list of all the public smart contracts on VeChain?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, abi

There are many public smart contracts on VeChain network, however, the ABI definition of those contracts is not publicly visible.

Is there a registry or GitHub repo where I can quickly find the reference of a smart contract function definition or signature? This will greatly help the development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The website to quickly search for a `signature` of a smart contract method or event:

https://b32.vecha.in

The collection of public available smart contracts JSON ABI are hosted on Github (https://github.com/vechain/b32) and you can make a "pull request" to submit your own smart contract ABI.

**Bonus points**: If your ABI JSON is submitted to the above mentioned repo, transactions related to your smart contract call can be decoded on-the-fly on the VeChain official explorer (https://explore.vechain.org)